# Regex Sublime to Java regex

Tags: java, regex, sublimetext3

i have this regex to delete comments in .c file(sublime 3 regex)

```
(^\/\/.*)|(\s+\/\/.*)|((\/\*)(.|\n)+?(\*\/))
```

Can i use this regex in java to use it programmatically?
If not, what regex should i use?
(P.S. i know, question us stupid a bit, but i don't know how to regex at all)

Comment: yes you can use it..you only need to double escape wherever the slashes are..
p.s. _i don't say that its correct regex for comment capturing_

Comment: it works in sublime, so it should in java, am i right?

Comment: yes it will..only you need to escape slashes..like `\s` to `\\s` and all others while using in Java

Comment: This is a very inefficient regex and it will most probably cause performance issues in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you have too many redundant capture groups inside the pattern, and the `(.|\n)+?` construct is very inefficient and may cause serious issues in Java (as with any other regex engine).

You can use a more streamlines expression that should not cause much redundant backtracking:

```
(?:^|\s+)//.*|/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cU7bO6/1). Use it with `Pattern.MULTILINE` flag (or add `(?m)` at the start of the pattern).

*Pattern explanation*:

- `(?:^|\s+)//.*` - (your  2 `(^\/\/.*)|(\s+\/\/.*)` branches  merged) single line comments at the start of a string or after the first 1+ whitespaces followed with `//` substring (including these whitespaces and forward slashes)
- `|` - or
- `/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/` - match multiline `/**/` comments

Java declaration:

```
String pattern = "(?m)(?:^|\\s+)//.*|/\\*[^*]*\\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\\*+)*/";
```

And a [sample code](http://ideone.com/zPTE2D):

```
String s =  "// Comment\ntex test\nMore text here // and comment 2\n/* More comments\nhere and\nhere */";
String pattern = "(?m)(?:^|\\s+)//.*|/\\*[^*]*\\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\\*+)*/";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll(pattern, ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work : `(?:/\\*(?:[^*]|(?:\\*+[^*/]))*\\*+/)|(?://.*)`

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/Ztghae)